# JPQL: "where" clause on "case" variable

Tags: jpa, case, jpql

The following JPQL query runs without issues:

```sql
SELECT t, CASE WHEN (e.language.language = 'en' AND e.language.country = 'GB' AND e.language.variant = '') THEN e.text ELSE '' END sortProperty FROM Glossary g JOIN g.terms t JOIN t.expressions e ORDER BY sortProperty
```

whereas the following fails:

```sql
SELECT t, CASE WHEN (e.language.language = 'en' AND e.language.country = 'GB' AND e.language.variant = '') THEN e.text ELSE '' END sortProperty FROM Glossary g JOIN g.terms t JOIN t.expressions e WHERE sortProperty = 'asdf' ORDER BY sortProperty
```

With this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid unbound variable "sortproperty" in query.
```

Is this a limitation in the query syntax and can this somehow be circumvented (perhaps using the Criteria API)?

Thanks and best regards,
Pascal

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to use setParameter("sortproperty", sortproperty) ??

Comment: @sabujhassan Thx for your response. sortProperty is not a parameter though, but a result variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem does not have direct connection to `CASE` expression, in general result variables (sortProperty in this case) cannot be used in `WHERE` clause. That's why also following is invalid JPQL:

```
SELECT u.firstName AS someVar FROM User u WHERE someVar = 'blaa'
```

Criteria API does not help here. Similar limitation exists also in SQL:

```
SELECT u.first_name as someAlias 
FROM users u 
-- someAlias is not known here:
WHERE someAlias = 'blaa'
```

Whole condition should be pushed to WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks @mikko-manu. I was able to move the condition from the CASE expression to the WHERE clause.